# Angular2 Outputs in ES5?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Here is an example code to demonstrate outputs in Angular 2 using ES5. But I get an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` error.

```
var SampleComponent10 = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "sampleten",
    outputs: ["click"],
    template: ""
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            this.click.next({});
        }.bind(this), 10000)
    }
})

var SampleComponent11 = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "sampleeleven",
    directives: [SampleComponent10],
    template: "<sampleten (click)='clicked($event)'></sampleten>"
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){
        this.clicked = function(e){
            console.log(e);
            console.log("Clicked");
        }
    }
})
```

Seems like there is some error in the template of SampleComponent11. But I am not able to catch it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like this:

```
var SampleComponent10 = ng.core.Component({
    selector: "sampleten",
    outputs: ["click"],
    template: ""
}).Class({
    constructor: function(){
        this.click = new ng.core.EventEmitter(); <== add this line
        setInterval(function(){
            this.click.next({});
        }.bind(this), 10000)
    }
})
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ts-to-js.html#!#property-metadata

Comment: But why `outputs` property is not working. Why do we need to manually assign it to a new instance of EventEmitter?

Comment: Because property click of your class-component is undefined.

Comment: And this line <sampleten (click)='clicked($event)'></sampleten> causes error

Comment: But I have added `outputs:['click']`. So how is it undefined.

Comment: I think it is only declaration