# Angular 2 ES6 - Sending event from component

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ecmascript-6, ionic2

I want to send an custom event from Component in ES6, so I can listen to it in template `<component (someEvent)="someFunction()">`, but i cannot make it happen.

`@Component's` properties `ouputs` or `events` are breaking the application. Am I missing something?

this is my Component declaration:

```
import {Component, Output} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'section-navigator-component',
    templateUrl: 'build/components/section_navigator/section_navigator.html',
    inputs: [ 'resources', 'attr' ],
    outputs: [ 'someEvent' ]
})


export class SectionNavigatorComponent {
    constructor() {

    }

    resourceClickHandler($event, resource) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you have tried and where you failed. Did you get an error message?

Comment: I've updated question

Comment: Are you importing someEvent correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by importing? Does someEvent has to be class extending some base Event class?

Comment: Well I don't think there is a key inputs or outputs in the component decorator, but I thought I missed somehting because API still changes a lot. And yes normally you would use it in the class `@Input()` or `@Output()` for events https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Input-var.html, don't forget to import the input and output decorators from the angular core

Comment: Does ES6 support decorators? I thought this was only supported in TypeScript.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Well he is using the `@Component`decorator. So I guess he is working with TypeScript. No, es6 doesn't support decorators.

Comment: @Cinkoskink either you are actually using TypeScript, then please update your question, or the question is a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36895505/angular2-outputs-in-es5

Comment: Ionic is using https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators, so maybe that's why I can use `@Component`. I am using ES6. I've updated my initial code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in your case:

```
import {Component, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'section-navigator-component',
    templateUrl: 'build/components/section_navigator/section_navigator.html',
    inputs: [ 'resources', 'attr' ],
    outputs: [ 'someEvent' ]
})


export class SectionNavigatorComponent {

    constructor() {
      this.someEvent = new EventEmitter();
    }

    resourceClickHandler($event, resource) {
      this.someEvent.emit(someValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was able to solve my problem thanks to your answer. You were close, the only thing that was missing is `import {EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core'`

Comment: Sad thing that it wasn't throwing any error. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to import 'Output' unless you use the alternate TypeScript syntax below:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'section-navigator-component',
    templateUrl: 'build/components/section_navigator/section_navigator.html'
})


export class SectionNavigatorComponent {
    @Input() resources: any;
    @Input() attr: any;

    @Output() someEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    constructor() {
    }

    resourceClickHandler($event, resource) {
      this.someEvent.emit(someValue);
    }
}
```